# Stock flow log connections in Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm actually doing a python script in AWS Lambda to transform statless logs from Flow Logs to statfull logs.

But I've some difficulties to save connections inside Lambda.

Variable "stock" is my list which will save connections

```
def init():
    global stock
    stock = []

def lambda_handler(event, context):
# retrieve bucket name and file_key from the S3 event
bucket_name = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
file_key = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
logger.info('Reading {} from {}'.format(file_key, bucket_name))
# get the object
obj = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=file_key)
if obj['ContentType'] =='application/x-gzip' or key.endswith('.gz'):
    lines_read = gzip.decompress(obj['Body'].read())
else:
    lines_read = obj['Body'].read()
        
lines_read = lines_read[3:-3]
lines = lines_read.decode().split("\n")
for line in lines:
    lines_split = line.split(" ")
    if lines_split[17] == "3" or lines_split[17] == "19":
        ts = str(time.time())
        line_whrite = ts + " " + "Short Connection " + lines_split[5] + " " + lines_split[6] + " " + lines_split[7] + " " + lines_split[8] + " " + lines_split[16]
    elif lines_split[17] == "1":
        i = 0
        ts = str(time.time())
        json2 = {"time": lines_split[15], "srcaddr": lines_split[5], "dstaddr": lines_split[6], "srcport": lines_split[7], "dstport": lines_split[8]}
        for connection in stock:
            if json2["srcaddr"] == connection["srcaddr"] or connection["dstaddr"] and json2["dstaddr"] == connection["srcaddr"] or connection["dstaddr"] and json2["srcport"] == connection["srcport"] or connection["dstport"] and json2["dstport"] == connection["srcport"] or connection["dstport"]: 
                tpsstart = int(json2["time"])
                tpsend = int(connection["time"])
                converted_tpsstart = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(round(tpsstart / 1000))
                converted_tpsend = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(round(tpsend / 1000))
                tpsdiff = converted_tpsend - converted_tpsstart
                line_whrite = "Connection Start :" + str(converted_tpsstart) + " Connection End:" + str(converted_tpsend) + " Connection Duration:" + str(tpsdiff) + " " + json2["srcaddr"] + " " + json2["dstaddr"] + " " + json2["srcport"] + " " + json2["dstport"]
                del stock[i]
                print(line_whrite)
            i = i + 1
```

The problem is (I think) that my variable "stock" is always reset so empty...

Do you have some idea ?

Thanks :)

Comment: Please refer [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/latest/serverless-architectures-lambda/writing-code-for-aws-lambdastatelessness-and-reuse.html) document from AWS. AWS Lambda is Stateless, you need to maintain such information into external storage/resources provided by AWS such as AWS System Parameter Store or AWS Secrete Manager or AWS S3 or AWS EFS or other. Depends upon your non-functional requirements..

Comment: Hello, thanks for your anwser.
Yes I'll do that is look like more easier !

Comment: Regardless of lambda or not, everytime your script finishes running all the variables are gone. Memory is not a storage location. Since the variable you are trying to loop over is connections, I think you might want to dynamically get it using boto3 instead of saving a list somewhere and then maintain it manually and painfully.

Comment: I didn't look too closely at what your code is trying to accomplish, but I notice that you have a `for` loop going through `stock`, and within that loop you `del stock[i]`. Removing items from a list while looping through the list probably isn't going to work the way you expect -- it might end up skipping-over items since the size of the list is changing.